# How to visualize embeddings when using a DNNCLassifier - Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I watced [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=1105s) tutorial to learn how to visualize embeddings on Tensorboard. The entire code is [here](https://gist.github.com/dandelionmane/4f02ab8f1451e276fea1f165a20336f1#file-mnist-py). He uses a convolutional neural network to train the model. Here is the core part of building the embeddings:

```
 embedding = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1024, embedding_size]), name="test_embedding")
 assignment = embedding.assign(embedding_input)

 config = tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.ProjectorConfig()
 embedding_config = config.embeddings.add()
 embedding_config.tensor_name = embedding.name
 embedding_config.sprite.image_path = LOGDIR + 'sprite_1024.png'
 embedding_config.metadata_path = LOGDIR + 'labels_1024.tsv'
 # Specify the width and height of a single thumbnail.
 embedding_config.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([28, 28])
 tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)
```

where `embedding_input` is the fully connected layer of the network.

I am using a `DNNCLassifier` object to classify cybernetic attacks. This is a piece of my code.

```
def input_fn(data_set):
    continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(data_set[k].values)
                    for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
    categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
                    indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(data_set[k].size)],
                    values=data_set[k].values,
                    dense_shape=[data_set[k].size, 1])
                        for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
    feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())
    label = tf.constant(data_set[LABEL_COLUMN].values)

    return feature_cols, label


def train_input_fn():
   return input_fn(training_set)

def eval_input_fn():
   return input_fn(test_set)

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(model_dir=model_dir,
        feature_columns=deep_columns,
        n_classes=5,
        hidden_units=[12, 4],
        label_keys=label_keys_values,
        optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
           learning_rate=0.1,
           l1_regularization_strength=0.001
        ))

classifier.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
```

Is there a way to get the output layer of the neural network from the DNNClassifier to use it as an `embedding_input`? I want to visualize the attack types as embeddings on Tensorboard.

Answer (score 1):

one way is use tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor

You can pass monitors params when you initialize your DNNClassifier

See https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/monitors

Comment: Thank you.  But I don't know what metric to use in my case (visualising clustered attacks, based on the output of the nn, on the Embedding section on Tensorboard)